# how to compute a%b recursively?

Tags: recursion, python-3.x

I need to write a recursive function that returns the remainder of two numbers. Here's what I wrote:

```
def remainder(a,b):
    if a==b:
        return 0
    else:
        k=a-b 
        return a-b + remainder(b,a-k)
```

If we test `remainder(5,3)` the function will return 2 and it's correct but if we test remainder(15,3),
we'll get 12 and its false. I just don't know how to debug it.

Comment: You want to do the same thing `%` does but without `%`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a case: (when a < b)

```
def remainder(a,b):
    if a<b: #trivial: remainder = a - b*0 = a
        return a
    else: #reduce the problem to a simple one
        return remainder(a-b, b)
```

Test:

```
print remainder(15,3)
```

Output:

```
0
```

Here if you are lazy and don't want to write more than 2 lines:

```
def remainder(a,b):
    return a if a < b else remainder(a-b, b)
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this :

```
def remainder(a,b):
if a<b:
    return a
else:
    return remainder(a-b,b)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
def remainder(a, b):
    if a < b:
        return a
    return remainder(a - b, b)
```

Examples:

```
>>> remainder(15, 3)
0
>>> remainder(14, 3)
2
>>> remainder(13, 3)
1
```

If `a < b` then it means we're done: we know the result of the computation and we can return `a`. Otherwise we need to subtract `b` from `a` and we call `remainder` again recursively. This can then repeatedly continue until `a` is smaller than `b`. Once that happens the recursion stops (i.e., it won't call `remainder` again) but we're able to return the result.